# Casting from Base Class to Instantiated Class Template

Tags: c++

I have several objects being instances of a Class Template. I need those objects to be stored in a `std::vector`. So I made the Class Template inherits from a Base Class:

```
class BaseValue
{
public:
  virtual void Test()
  {
    std::cout << "BaseValue::Test()" << std::endl;
  }
};

template<class T>
class TemplateValue : public BaseValue
{
public:
  TemplateValue(const T &value) : m_value(value)
  {
  }

  virtual void Test()
  {
    std::cout << "TemplateValue::Test() => " << m_value << std::endl;
  }

  T GetValue() const
  {
    return m_value;
  }

  void SetValue(const T &value)
  {
    m_value = value;
  }

private:
  T m_value;
};
```

Based on this, I would like to do something similar to this:

```
  TemplateValue<double> *VDouble1 = new TemplateValue<double>(42.42);
  TemplateValue<std::string> *VString2 = new TemplateValue<std::string>("Hi!");
  TemplateValue<double> *VDouble3 = new TemplateValue<double>(0);
  TemplateValue<std::string> *VString4 = new TemplateValue<std::string>("");

  std::vector<BaseValue *> values{VDouble1, VString2, VDouble3, VString4};

  // Error: class BaseValue has no member "SetValue"
  // Error: class BaseValue has no member "GetValue"
  values[2]->SetValue(values[0]->GetValue());
  values[3]->SetValue(values[1]->GetValue());
```

How could I do that? I was thinking about storing a `typeId` in the base class and use this to cast the `BaseValue` into their respective `TemplateValue<T>` and then calling `SetValue(const T &value)` but not sure this is a clean solution.

**NOTES**

- I have no idea what are the T's actually. Some may be added in the future and it should still work.

Comment: Is the ' ] ' a typo in your `TemplateValue` constructor ?

Comment: Why not make `SetValue` and `GetValue` also virtual members of `BaseValue`?

Comment: For GetValue it would work. But for SetValue? Their parameters are different actually. Or I could do something like virtual BaseValue::SetValue(void *)=0 and then cast in the instantiated class template?

Comment: @Korchkidu - Looks like you want to implement/reinvent `boost::any`:  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I just simplified to get a minimal example. It is more complicated actually. I need several methods doing the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on @joseph-mansfield who suggested:

***"Why not make SetValue and GetValue also virtual members of BaseValue?"***

What I did:

**In BaseValue:**

```
  virtual void SetValue(const BaseValue *bv) = 0;
```

**In TemplateValue**

```
  void SetValue(const BaseValue *bv)
  {
    auto tv = static_cast<const TemplateValue<T>*>(bv);
    m_value = tv->m_value;
  }
```

**In Main**

```
  values[2]->SetValue(values[0]);
  values[3]->SetValue(values[1]);
```

The only problem is that it relies on `static_cast` so if the given type is not correct, I am in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing compile time polymorphism with runtime polymorphism is most impossible. I would say you can't do that like you try it now.

But you can use a specific type insteed of the template type. For example [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html) if you have a known amount of types you want to provide.

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

using my_variants = boost::variant<int, std::string>;

class value {
public:

    value(const my_variants &value) : m_value(value) {}


    my_variants set() const {
        return m_value;
    }

    void get(const my_variants &value) {
        m_value = value;
    }

private:
    my_variants m_value;
};
```

[see this running example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32f0738e5a31651d)

Comment: I do not know the T types in my template actually. Is it possible to use boost::variant with any TemplateValue<T> then? T may be classes defined by others.

Comment: there is a [boost.any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html) type which probably can do what you want (i never used it yet).